# See Service Worker Changes During Iterative Development

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

Is there a better way to work with service-workers and/or Workbox in development so that I can instantly see changes in the browser?  Each time I make a change to a Service Worker, I need to `npm build` and serve that build to see changes (which I think is very time consuming).